# How can I receive combinations of two/one finger and single/double taps in hammer.js

Tags: hammer.js

I'm attempting to receive three types of tap events using hammer.js

1. single tap with one finger
2. double tap with one finger
3. double tap with two fingers

How can I set this up correctly in hammer.js

Here is what I currently have:

```
  if (mc == null) {
    mc = new Hammer.Manager(el);
  }
  mc.set({ touchAction: "none" });
  //mc.get("swipe").set({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, pointers: 2});'
  //mc.get('tap').set({enable: false});
  var singletap = new Hammer.Tap({
    event: "singletap",
    taps: 1,
    pointers: 1
  });

  var doubletap = new Hammer.Tap({
    event: "doubletap",
    taps: 2,
    pointers: 1
  });
  var twodoubletap = new Hammer.Tap({
    event: "twodoubletap",
    taps: 2,
    pointers: 2
  });

  mc.add([twodoubletap, doubletap,singletap]);//, twotap, threetap]);

  twodoubletap.recognizeWith([doubletap,singletap])
  doubletap.recognizeWith([singletap,twodoubletap])

  //doubletap.requireFailure(twodoubletap);

  singletap.requireFailure([doubletap,twodoubletap]);

  mc.on("twodoubletap doubletap singletap", binding.value);
```

I can get a single tap to fire consistently and a one finger double tap sometimes.

The two-finger double tap either does not fire, or fires along with a one other taps following it immediately.

Ideally, I would like each type of tap to fire consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing three things.
1. I added dropRequireFailure to the two-fingerdouble tap for the other taps
2. I made the thresholds larger in the events.
3. I added a time-based filter in the event handler that rejects taps too close to each other. I know this isn't ideal but it works for now.

```
          if (mc == null) {
            mc = new Hammer.Manager(el);
          }
          mc.set({ touchAction: "none" });
          //mc.get("swipe").set({direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, pointers: 2});'
          //mc.get('tap').set({enable: false});
          var singletap = new Hammer.Tap({
            event: "singletap",
            taps: 1,
            pointers: 1,
            interval: 500,
            threshold: 200,
            posThreshold: 200
          });

          var doubletap = new Hammer.Tap({
            event: "doubletap",
            taps: 2,
            pointers: 1,
            interval: 300,
            threshold: 200,
            posThreshold: 200
          });
          var twodoubletap = new Hammer.Tap({
            event: "twodoubletap",
            taps: 2,
            pointers: 2,
            interval: 400,
            threshold: 500,
            posThreshold: 200
          });

          mc.add([twodoubletap, doubletap,singletap]);//, twotap, threetap]);

          twodoubletap.recognizeWith([doubletap,singletap])
          doubletap.recognizeWith([twodoubletap])

          doubletap.requireFailure(twodoubletap);
          singletap.requireFailure([doubletap,twodoubletap]);
          twodoubletap.dropRequireFailure(doubletap);
          twodoubletap.dropRequireFailure(singletap);

          mc.on("twodoubletap doubletap singletap", handler);
```

Then at the top of the event handler:

```
      let now = Date.now();
      if((now - lastTap)<500){
        return;
      }
      lastTap = now;
```